# How to stop Glassfish server on Mac when developing Java EE web application when using Netbeans and Mac?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, web-applications, glassfish

I'm new to web application development using java ee, netbeans and mac.  I initially decided to use glassfish as my server, but later I have changed my mind and decided to use tomcat instead.

When I created a web application project that include a tomcat server and tried to run it, I got error "Deployment error:Starting of Tomcat failed, the server port 8080 is already in use". I think it is due to the fact that my previous Glassfish server is using the port. How to stop the Glassfish server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*asadmin* is the command for controlling glassfish.  Specifically, you want to stop the currently running domain.

To get a list of domains, try:

```
asadmin list-domains
```

To stop a given domain, try:

```
asadmin stop-domain <yourdomain>
```

Comment: To do it through NetBeans, look for the services tab and control it there

Answer (score 1):

Incase asadmin stop-domain or stopping through Netbeans is not successful, try to kill the process. In some cases, java out of memory exception occurs and port wouldn't get released.

killall -9 glassfish

or

killall -9 java